# PHP 5.4 upgrade broke matrix 2.4.1 9 (EE 2.5.4)

Tags: matrix

I have recently been asked to look at an EE-based site which is currently broken.

The issue is that where matrix fields occur in the template, it appears they are not parsed and instead are just echoed back, for example:

```
{main_image}
    {matrix_image_title}
{/main_image}
```

It seems this happened when the host upgraded to PHP 5.4.

I have creating a staging version of the site and have managed to resolve the issue by switching the PHP version to 5.3.28 from 5.4.28.  However it is not an option to do this on the live site.

Having consulted documentation it seems that the version of expression engine (2.5.4) and the version of matrix (2.4.1) should fully support PHP 5.4 so I'm a little at a loss as to how to further investigate this issue.

So, aside from changing hosts to one that supports PHP 5.3, can anyone else suggest routes of investigation, solutions or explanations as to why this might be happening?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: Can I ask why you haven't upgraded to the current version of Matrix?

Comment: I second that. Why not just update EE and Matrix?

Comment: I did upgrade matrix to the latest, but that did not resolve it. 

I've not been able to upgrade ee as I'm not the orig developer I can't download the latest licenced version. I may be able to get hold of it with a bit of digging, but am a little wary upgrading ee could introduce issues elsewhere.

Comment: Two things I see here. First, if the host is not willing to help by providing PHP 5.3 as an immediate option, you should probably shop for a better host. Second, ExpressionEngine 2.5.4 is nearly [two years old](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-4) at the time of this comment, so rather than looking solely for a quick fix, I would look at the bigger picture and investigate bringing the installation and add-ons up to date. That will be the best thing for the site and client in the long run.